# Python reading logfile with timestamp including microseconds

Tags: python, datetime, time

I've got a timestamp in a log file with the format like:

```
2010-01-01 18:48:14.631829
```

I've tried the usual suspects like strptime, and no matter what i do, I'm getting that it doesn't match the format I specify. `("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" OR "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")`

I've even tried splitting the value by "." so I can just compare vs the value not having the microseconds on it, but it STILL tells me it doesn't match: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

Ug, all I need to do is a simple time delta, haha. Why is python's time stuff so scattered? time, datetime, other various imports

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strptime` like so (Python 2.6+ only):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s = "2010-01-01 18:48:14.631829"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1, 18, 48, 14, 631829)
```

Docs: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

> ...
>
> `%f` Microsecond as a decimal number [0,999999], zero-padded on the left
>
> ...

If your on 2.5- *and* you don't care about the micros, you can just chop it off:

```
>>> import re
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(re.sub('\..*', '', s), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1, 18, 48, 14)
```

Comment: %f is a bad directive. I'm assuming it's because i'm on python 2.5?

Comment: Ah yes, I get `ValueError: 'f' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'` in Python 2.5 – never noticed.

Comment: fair enough. splitting off the microseconds works well enough with this, though =D thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course, splitting the string *does* work:

```
>>> print s
2010-01-01 18:48:14.631829
>>> time.strptime(s.split('.')[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=18, tm_min=48, tm_sec=14, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me (Python 2.6):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> string1 = '2010-01-01 18:48:14.631829'
>>> string2 = '2010-01-09 13:04:39.540268'
>>> time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(string1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(string2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> time2 - time1
datetime.timedelta(7, 65784, 908439)
```

i.e., there are 7 days, 65784 seconds and 908439 microseconds between the two dates. See the [datetime docs](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) for information on the `timedelta` object.

**Edit:** Try the following if you cannot use the `%f` directive:

```
>>> time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(string1.split('.')[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(string2.split('.')[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> time2 - time1
datetime.timedelta(7, 65785)
```